# Inheritance in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8, typescript1.5, typescript1.6, typescript1.4

Is that possible inheritance features in Typescript and other features like overloading, overriding etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
    constructor(theName: string) { this.name = theName; }
    move(distanceInMeters: number = 0) {
        console.log(`${this.name} moved ${distanceInMeters}m.`);
    }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    move(distanceInMeters = 5) {
        console.log("Slithering...");
        super.move(distanceInMeters);
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    move(distanceInMeters = 45) {
        console.log("Galloping...");
        super.move(distanceInMeters);
    }
}

let sam = new Snake("Sammy the Python");
let tom: Animal = new Horse("Tommy the Palomino");

sam.move();
tom.move(34);
```

Comment: lage raho bhaiyon :D